# Some SVG files do not work on safari

Tags: css, html, svg, safari

I created SVG files via adobe illustrator. But these files do not work on Safari. It works on Chrome and Firefox.

You can see in this web site : https://www.communityinviter.com/

Comment: This website has a certificate with a bad domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari still have some problems on svg rendering, try to change the embed tag from img to:

```
<iframe src="your-svg.svg"></iframe>
<embed src="your-svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
<object data="your-svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

or simply try to include your svg inline:

```
<svg width:"10%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

or using the js modernizr library(https://modernizr.com/) you can prevent old browser bad rendering or elements hiding displaying a png instead in this way:

```
if (!Modernizr.svg) {
    $(".yourimg").attr("src", "images/svg.png");
}
```

Comment: i use this and its worked. Tank you so much. I love you man <3

<object data="your-svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>